# mysqlclient install issue with python3.10

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I've try both `pip install mysqlclient` also `pip install mysql` all of them printing out tons of error.

I guess there was an issue with mysql.h or something, by try to read a 'not very friendly' error output+few or none knowledge about MS c/cpp stuff. Thankyou for helping/information.

````
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t5j4bxvg\\mysqlclient_d6e4e662a9ea40f7a66eca6cff3748d3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t5j4bxvg\\mysqlclient_d6e4e662a9ea40f7a66eca6cff3748d3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-reyouabu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t5j4bxvg\mysqlclient_d6e4e662a9ea40f7a66eca6cff3748d3\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb -IC:\Program Files\Python310\include -IC:\Program Files\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t5j4bxvg\\mysqlclient_d6e4e662a9ea40f7a66eca6cff3748d3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\%USER%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t5j4bxvg\\mysqlclient_d6e4e662a9ea40f7a66eca6cff3748d3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-reyouabu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: `pip` is trying to compile from source, and under Windows that is not always straightforward, especially when, as here, the supplied source code does `#include mysql.h` but that file is not bundled in the source. Normally I would recommend getting an unofficial `mysqlclient` Windows binary from Christoph Gohlke's site, but at the moment there isn't one for Python 3.10. You could try looking for the file that is missing.